# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, migration, laravel-8

I am building an application using Laravel 8 and SQLite when I am trying to migrate `php artisan migrate` this error appears `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database`.
I tried to search for a solution and most of the answers were to give permission to the file using `sudo chmod -R 775` but the problem that I am not able to run this command on windows
How can I solve this error?

Comment: In windows you can right-click on the file and uncheck the "read-only"  attribute if it's checked. If it's not then go to the security tab and give write permission to your user. There's probably commandline or powershell ways to do this but I don't know them though

Comment: It is unchecked and the have added most of the users to the security but still notsolved

Comment: Do you already check with this https://www.ringingliberty.com/2020/11/02/sqlstatehy000-general-error-8-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database/?

Comment: This one also talks about the Linux machines but I am working on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem
The issue occurred because of the avast antivirus. When I disabled it, the error disappeared